# How remove or fix broken symbolic link?

Tags: linux-mint, find, symlink

In my case this is the problem

```
~ $ find ./ -type l -exec file {} \; |grep broken
./.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/lock: broken symbolic link to 127.0.1.1:+3704
```

Comment: How do you want to fix the broken links?

Comment: `find -xtype l` is a simpler way to find broken symlinks

Answer (score 2):

Since it’s only a lock file there should be no problem with simply deleting it. You can remove the symbolic link with:

```
rm ./.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/lock
```

If you had a new file you want to point the symbolic link to you could then re-create it using:

```
ln -s /path/to/target ./.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/lock
```